# Can you test if a mixin exists?

Tags: sass, mixins

Sass quick question (hopefully) here. Can you test for the existence of a mixin? e.g.

```
@if thumbnail-mixin {} @else { //define mixin }.
```

Ideally I'd use `@unless`, but that only exists on a fork. I'm aware you can overwrite a mixin but I'm thinking more if you can have a default mixin, rather than having to specify N variables in every case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sass does not currently have native functionality to determine if a mixin exists or not.

https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/561#issuecomment-14430978

You could create a Sass function written in Ruby:

```
def mixin_exists(mixin_name)
    if(environment.mixin(mixin_name.value))
      Sass::Script::Bool.new(true)
    else
      Sass::Script::Bool.new(false)
    end
end
```

Or you could use the [sass-utilities Compass extension](https://github.com/edwardoriordan/sass-utilities), which has this function included.

Answer (score 27):

The most recent version of Sass [(v3.3.0)](http://rubygems.org/gems/sass/) has a `mixin-exists` function:

```
.foo {
  @if mixin-exists(mymixin) {
    exists: true;
  }
  @else {
    exists: false;
  }
}
```

Sass v3.3 adds other existence tests too:

```
variable-exists($name)
global-variable-exists($name)
function-exists($name)
```

[More on Sass v3.3.](https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/master/doc-src/SASS_CHANGELOG.md#smaller-improvements)