# Test whether a Sass function is defined

Tags: sass

How can I test if a Sass function exists?

---

I have a Sass package that uses a custom Sass function. However, outside Ruby (e.g. libsass), that function may not be defined and a fallback is provided:

`url: if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('name.eot'), 'name.eot')`

I would like to set the value of `$bootstrap-sass-asset-helper` to true or false depending on whether `twbs-font-path` is declared.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current version of Sass has a `function-exists` function.  [Full example](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7916488):

```
.foo {
  @if function-exists(myfunc) {
    exists: true;
  }
  @else {
    exists: false;
  }
}
```

This is new functionality to v3.3 (March 2014), so you may need to update your Sass gem to utilize it.

Sass v3.3 adds other existence tests too:

```
variable-exists($name)
global-variable-exists($name)
mixin-exists($name)
```

[More on Sass v3.3.](https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/master/doc-src/SASS_CHANGELOG.md#smaller-improvements)

Answer (score 7):

Sass does not have such a feature.  You could fudge it like this if you needed to:

```
@debug if(foo() == unquote("foo()"), false, true); // false

@function foo() {
    @return true;
}

@debug if(foo() == unquote("foo()"), false, true); // true
```

This works because when you call a function that doesn't exist, Sass assumes that you might be writing valid CSS (calc, linear-gradient, attr, etc.).  When this happens, what you've got is a string.  So if the function exists, you get the results of the function instead of a string.  So `foo() == unquote("foo()")` is just checking to see if you got a string or not.

Related:  [Can you test if a mixin exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494555/sass-can-you-test-if-a-mixin-exists)

Comment: Thanks for the fudge, could you please elaborate on `foo() == unquote("foo()")`?

Comment: I've amended my answer, I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Awesome and appalling hack :) will wait a couple of days before accepting so I can attach bounty.