# Using a function in Sass is returning the string containing the name of the function rather than the result

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I'm trying Zurb Foundation 5.

So, I've created a new project and try changing settings. When I changed, for example, `$row-width: rem-calc(1170);` in my-project/scss/settings.scss, it compiled (in my-project/stylesheets/app.css) into:

```
.row {
  max-width: rem-calc(1170);
}
```

It seems like it doesn't know about rem-calc function.
How to make it calculate rem-calc properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function doesn't exist.  You must declare it (or import it from another file) before you use it.  Sass does not throw errors for non-existent functions because they have a similar syntax to CSS functions.  So it assumes that if it isn't a Sass function that it must be a CSS function.

Related:  [Test whether a Sass function is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706908/test-whether-a-sass-function-is-defined)

Comment: I've done @import "foundation/functions"; in settings.scss and now it working, thanks