# image_url vs image-url Rails 4.2 SCS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I am converting an old Rails 3.2 project to Rails 4.2 and noticed my image and font assets were not being properly loaded. There were no errors in the rails server log or shown on the development console of Chrome, but the images and fonts were not showing up on the page.

Using RubyMine and looking at the `scss` file, I noticed that the IDE was complaining about the use of `image-path` and `font-path`. When I changed the hyphens to underscores (`image_path` `font_path`), the images and fonts showed up on the web page.

Was there a recent change to make hyphenated functions no longer work? Are the hyphenated and underscore functions aliases to each other?

The underscore function names appear here (inside of sass_functions inside of sprockets):

```
require 'sass'

module Sprockets
  module SassFunctions
    def asset_path(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new(sprockets_context.asset_path(path.value), :string)
    end

    def asset_url(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new("url(" + sprockets_context.asset_path(path.value) + ")")
    end

    def image_path(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new(sprockets_context.image_path(path.value), :string)
    end

    def image_url(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new("url(" + sprockets_context.image_path(path.value) + ")")
    end

    def video_path(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new(sprockets_context.video_path(path.value), :string)
    end

    def video_url(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new("url(" + sprockets_context.video_path(path.value) + ")")
    end

    def audio_path(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new(sprockets_context.audio_path(path.value), :string)
    end

    def audio_url(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new("url(" + sprockets_context.audio_path(path.value) + ")")
    end

    def font_path(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new(sprockets_context.font_path(path.value), :string)
    end

    def font_url(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new("url(" + sprockets_context.font_path(path.value) + ")")
    end

    def javascript_path(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new(sprockets_context.javascript_path(path.value), :string)
    end

    def javascript_url(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new("url(" + sprockets_context.javascript_path(path.value) + ")")
    end

    def stylesheet_path(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new(sprockets_context.stylesheet_path(path.value), :string)
    end

    def stylesheet_url(path)
      ::Sass::Script::String.new("url(" + sprockets_context.stylesheet_path(path.value) + ")")
    end

    protected
      def sprockets_context
        options[:sprockets][:context]
      end

      def sprockets_environment
        options[:sprockets][:environment]
      end
  end
end
```

- sass-3.4.10
- rails-4.2.0
- sass-rails-5.0.1
- sprockets-2.12.3

Comment: Sass doesn't provide image-path or font-path helpers.  It is possible to write custom Sass functions in Ruby that don't allow hyphen and underscore to be interchangeable.

Comment: I'm guessing OP is using the [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) gem, which does provide sass functions with hyphenated names. OP, you say that the IDE complains, but you didn't say whether or not the code actually works. Does it?

Comment: @Jordan - good catch, it is the sass-rails gem. I'll try to clarify in my question, but the hyphenated function names do not work. There is no error thrown, but the images and fonts did not show up. Once I changed to the underscore methods, the assets did show up

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588136/using-a-function-in-sass-is-returning-the-string-containing-the-name-of-the-func

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/65) is relevant. It describes the same problem, and a solution is now reflected [in the sass-rails README](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/blob/master/README.md#important-note):

> Sprockets provides some directives that are placed inside of comments called `require`, `require_tree`, and `require_self`. **DO NOT USE THEM IN YOUR SASS/SCSS FILES.** They are very primitive and do not work well with Sass files. Instead, use Sass's native `@import` directive which `sass-rails` has customized to integrate with the conventions of your Rails projects.