# SCSS compiling error: expecting color

Tags: joomla, sass, materialize

Live page in question:

http://a.nyaii.com

There is an error when .scss file is being compiled. I'm not unfamiliar with HTML/CSS, but .scss is totally new to me, so I have no clue how to fix this. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

This page is built with Gantry 5 template using joomla. After I include .scss files from [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) I get this error.

Related lines are:

**line triggering error** Found in _variables.scss line 2-3

```
$primary-color: color("materialize-red", "lighten-2") !default;
$primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%) !default;
```

**definition of function color** Found in _color.scss line 402

```
  @function color($color, $type) {
    @if map-has-key($colors, $color) {
      $curr_color: map-get($colors, $color);
      @if map-has-key($curr_color, $type) {
        @return map-get($curr_color, $type);
      }
    }
    @warn "Unknown `#{name}` in $colors.";
    @return null;
  }
```

**definition of $colors** Found in _color.css line 340

```
$colors: (
  "materialize-red": $materialize-red,
  "red": $red,
  "pink": $pink,
  "purple": $purple,
  "deep-purple": $deep-purple,
  "indigo": $indigo,
  "blue": $blue,
  "light-blue": $light-blue,
  "cyan": $cyan,
  "teal": $teal,
  "green": $green,
  "light-green": $light-green,
  "lime": $lime,
  "yellow": $yellow,
  "amber": $amber,
  "orange": $orange,
  "deep-orange": $deep-orange,
  "brown": $brown,
  "blue-grey": $blue-grey,
  "grey": $grey,
  "shades": $shades
);
```

**definition of $materialize-red** Found in _color.css line 10

```
$materialize-red: (
  "lighten-5":  #fdeaeb,
  "lighten-4":  #f8c1c3,
  "lighten-3":  #f3989b,
  "lighten-2":  #ee6e73,
  "lighten-1":  #ea454b,
  "base":       #e51c23,
  "darken-1":   #d0181e,
  "darken-2":   #b9151b,
  "darken-3":   #a21318,
  "darken-4":   #8b1014,
);
```

Above codes can be found here:
http://a.nyaii.com/templates/rt_antares/custom/scss/materialize.scss
http://a.nyaii.com/templates/rt_antares/custom/scss/components/_variables.scss
http://a.nyaii.com/templates/rt_antares/custom/scss/components/_color.scss

All dependencies can be found here
http://a.nyaii.com/templates/rt_ambrosia/custom/scss/components/

Comment: There's not enough code here to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Main question editted to provide more links to related scss files and dependencies

Comment: I can't reproduce the error: http://sassmeister.com/gist/018a42d31a1ff03de822, but there is only 1 way to get the "not a color" error... by passing in something that is not a color (eg, a string, a null value, etc.).  Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588136/using-a-function-in-sass-is-returning-the-string-containing-the-name-of-the-func

Comment: I am not very familiar with scss, but could it be the "lighten" is not defined? I take it is something like a function, I try to search other dependencies but couldn't find a line defining it.

Comment: [Lighten is a native function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html), the fact that you're feeding it something that is not a color (presumably because you're trying to call a function that doesn't exist yet) is the problem.

Comment: I've editted the main question, adding more code details. Upon reading the codes I don't find anything that would provoke the error: `$primary-color` is invoking custom function `color`, `color` looks into `$colors` and finds `materialize-red` and assign its value to local variable $curr_color. The value being $materialize-red, function `color` should be able to return  `$materialize-red.lighten-2`, which is `#ee6e73` to `$primary_color`. 

After all, this is from a working package, it is unlikely there is any code error in it. So could it be the compiler?

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem using Sassmeister, we can't help you.

Comment: Any luck fixing this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Are you also using gantry 5+materializeCSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug because Gantry5 uses sass 3.2 as compiler, they are working on it. See https://github.com/gantry/gantry5/issues/1117