# Bootstrap-sass is outputting calls to font-path

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, gulp-sass

When ever I compile using `gulp-sass` on node the following scss

```
@import "_bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "_bootstrap";
```

I get this in the output

```
src: url(font-path("bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"));
```

However, the `font-path` thing isn't in the [precompiled boostrap](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css)

```
src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
```

Why does mine have `font-path`? Is this a sass function, and if so why isn't it calling it and how do I get an error and how do I resolve this error?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588136/using-a-function-in-sass-is-returning-the-string-containing-the-name-of-the-func

Answer (score 0):

Sprockets is something unique to Rails. Simply remove it and all should work..

```
//@import "_bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "_bootstrap";
```