# Webpack sass-loader with bootstrap

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-sass, sass-loader

I have just got my head into webpack but it has now thrown a fit when i try to include bootstrap-sass from the index.scss file.

This webpack conf works great and outputs a .css file to css/stylehseet.css

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        stylesheet: path.resolve(__dirname, 'scss/index.scss')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname),
        filename: 'bundle.bootstrap-sass.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    'style', // backup loader when not building .css file
                    'css!sass' // loaders to preprocess CSS
                )
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].css')
    ],
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: [
            './node_modules'
        ]
    }
};
```

The problem is, in the index.scss I have to include bootstrap-sass.
 index.scss, which according to the https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader#imports you add a ~ and webpack should then resolve it all:

```
$icon-font-path: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

Problem is in my attempts it isn't :/. I get the output:

```
Hash: b59b46e5946e7ab3d888
Version: webpack 1.13.3
Time: 1852ms
                   Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.bootstrap-sass.js  171 kB       0  [emitted]  css
    + 9 hidden modules

ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
Module parse failed: /mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (/mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2756:10)
    at Parser.pp$7.readToken (/mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2477:17)
    at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (/mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2468:15)
    at Parser.parse (/mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:515:10)
    at Object.parse (/mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./scss/index.scss 6:4172-4253 6:4276-4357

ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
..... etc etc
```

Webpack is fairly powerful but it does take you round the houses to get going...
This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "John Carmichael",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "latest",
    "node-sass": "^3.11.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }
}
```

Is there something minor I am missing that anyone can spot :)  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
Module parse failed: /mnt/4E6E45D36E45B48D/Work/webpack-demo/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

There's your problem.

The compliler is trying to load an `.eot` font file, but it doesn't know what to do with it, because you have not used an appropriate loader.

First, installl the `file-loader` and the `url-loader` in your dev dependencies, like so: `npm install file-loader url-loader -D`

Then, add these in your loaders

```
{
    test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
},
{
    test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
},
{
    test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: 'file-loader'
},
```

This way you will be able to load most types of fonts

Comment: Ah ha! thank you! Your answer in combination with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34639720/webpack-font-include-issue#answer-36635363 helped me get to the bottom of this. Still not 100% sure i get this webpack stuff yet ;)

Comment: Also, anyone else reading this.. don't forget to add the url-loader and file-loader to your package json

Comment: @John Oops, you are right, I assumed you had them. Will add in the answer to be complete

Comment: Thanks John, it's work for me as well. The answer of Dimitris Karagiannis passed Unexpected character '�' (1:0), but I got another error is *.ttf Unexpected character '' (1:0)

Comment: @HuyNguyen Can you paste the error lines from "ERROR in..." to "...(1:0)"?

Comment: @Dimitris Karagiannis: Full error message is:
ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

Module parse failed: /react/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf Unexpected character '' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.